# need toggle to work

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I want the collapsible panel in toggle to close when clicking anywhere outside the toggle and show the `+`. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#toggle li').click(function () {
    var siler = $(this).children('.collapse');
    if (siler.is(':hidden')) {
      siler.slideDown('200');
      $(this).children('span').html('--');  
    } else {
      siler.slideUp('200');
      $(this).children('span').html('+');
    }
  });
});

$('#toggle li > .collapse:eq(0)').hide();

$(document).click(function(event) {
  if ( !$(event.target).hasClass('#toggle li > .collapse')) {
    $("#toggle li > .collapse").hide();
    $(this).children('span').html('+'); 
  }
});
```

A fiddle for you to play with

http://jsfiddle.net/krishkam2610/Ss3xU/13/

Comment: Just a note you had your `$.ready()` within an implcit `$.load()` (courtesy, jsfiddle). Here it is fixed for *that* problem: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Ss3xU/15/

Comment: You should refrain from `$(document).click(function (event) {`. Not only is it a shortcut and a bit "lazy" (ahem!), but it's also horribly counterproductive, since you're telling the browser to process *every click event* that occurs on the page. *Don't do that.* Use `$('#content').on('click', '.subselector', func...)` or `$('.reasonable-parent').on('click', func...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are complicating the code too much. Why don't you try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggle li').click(function () {
        a = $(this).children(".plusminus");
        $(this).children(".panel").slideToggle('fast', function(){
            a.html($(this).is(":visible") ? '--' : '+');
        });
    });
    $("body").click(function(event){
        if ($(event.target).closest("ul").attr('id') != "toggle") {
            $("#toggle li > .panel").slideUp();
            $('.plusminus').html('+');
        }
    });
});
```

#### Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Ss3xU/20/)

---

Update according to comment.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggle li').click(function () {
        $("#toggle li > .panel").slideUp();
        $('.plusminus').html('+');
        a = $(this).children(".plusminus");
        $(this).children(".panel").slideToggle('fast', function(){
            a.html($(this).is(":visible") ? '--' : '+');
        });
    });
    $("body").click(function(event){
        if ($(event.target).closest("ul").attr('id') != "toggle") {
            $("#toggle li > .panel").slideUp();
            $('.plusminus').html('+');
        }
    });
});
```

#### Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Ss3xU/21/)

---

Update according to comment.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle li > .panel").hide();
    $('.plusminus').html('+');
    $('#toggle li').click(function () {
        $("#toggle li > .panel").slideUp();
        $('.plusminus').html('+');
        a = $(this).children(".plusminus");
        $(this).children(".panel").slideToggle('fast', function(){
            a.html($(this).is(":visible") ? '--' : '+');
        });
    });
    $("body").click(function(event){
        if ($(event.target).closest("ul").attr('id') != "toggle") {
            $("#toggle li > .panel").slideUp();
            $('.plusminus').html('+');
        }
    });
});
```

#### Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Ss3xU/22/)

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle li > .panel").hide();
    $('.plusminus').html('+');
    $('#toggle li').click(function () {
        if( !$(this).children('.panel').is(":visible") ) {
            $("#toggle li > .panel").slideUp();
            $('.plusminus').html('+');
        }
        a = $(this).children(".plusminus");
        $(this).children(".panel").slideToggle('fast', function(){
            a.html($(this).is(":visible") ? '--' : '+');
        });
    });
    $("body").click(function(event){
        if ($(event.target).closest("ul").attr('id') != "toggle") {
            $("#toggle li > .panel").slideUp();
            $('.plusminus').html('+');
        }
    });
});
```

#### Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Ss3xU/26/)

Comment: hi praveen is it possible if need a condition in which when i click on any item contained in <p></p> within panel, it may remain opened till i click over the plusminus or anywhere outside the toggle, and that without changing much in the script. i tried all ways to make it work but could not succeed.

Comment: Yeah, possible. Lemme think about it.

Comment: looking forward to get your comment back, by the way thanx for efforts.

Comment: @kamalbhardwaj Then you should not give the handler to the click event of the `P` as it is the container. We will need to have a separate element inside `P` that is clickable and you can achieve what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. I think thatz what you want.
`Fiddle`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#toggle li').bind('click', function(){

                $(this).children('.panel').toggle();
                var a = $(this).children('span').html()=="-"?"+":"-";
                $(this).children('span').html(a);

        });
});
```